# Unable to login to localhost CVAT

Tags: localhost, cvat

I am using **CVAT** through the localhost and I reinstall the Brave browser , then I tried to login to CVAT but it is not logged; i am sure about the password and username.

***This error shows when I am trying to login :***

**
Could not login on the server

Error: Request failed with status code 400. {"non_field_errors":["Unable to log in with provided credentials."]}.**

***and this is when i tried to reset the password :***

Could not reset password on the server.

Error: Request failed with status code 500. "\n<!doctype html>\n\n\n Server Error (500)\n\n\nServer Error (500)

\n\n\n".

I need to get access to the account.

Comment: are you sure you are in control of the server?